# Given ring morphisms $R \to A$, $R \to R'$, $\Omega_{A \otimes_R R'/R'} = \Omega_{A/R} \otimes_A (A \otimes_R R')$

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R \to A$ be a morphism of rings, making $A$ into an $R$-algebra. Denote the module of differentials of $A$ over $R$ by $\Omega_{A/R}$, with exterior derivative $d_{A/R}: A \to \Omega_{A/R}$. Let $R \to R'$ be a ring homomorphism and denote $A' = A \otimes_R R'$. I am trying to show that $\Omega_{A'/R'} = \Omega_{A/R} \otimes_A A'$, with exterior derivative $d_{A'/R'} = d_{A/R} \otimes_R id_{R'}$ - here, I am using the identification $\Omega_{A/R} \otimes_R R' \simeq \Omega_{A/R} \otimes_A A'$ with $m \otimes_R r' = m \otimes_A (1 \otimes_R r')$, for $m \in \Omega_{A/R}, r' \in R'$. Thus, $d_{A'/R'}(x \otimes r') = d_{A/R}(x) \otimes_A (1 \otimes_R r')$, for $x \in A, r' \in R'$. I then tried to show that $(\Omega_{A/R} \otimes_A A', d_{A/R} \otimes_R id_{R'})$ satisfies the universal property defining the module of differentials. Here's what I've done so far:

Let $M$ be an $A'$-module and $d: A' \to M$ be a derivation of $A'$ into $M$ over $R'$. Then, considering the canonical morphism $\iota: A \to A', x \mapsto x \otimes1$, we can make $M$ into an $A$-module and $\tilde{d} = d \circ \iota$ is a derivation of $A$ into $M$ over $R$. By the universal property of the module of differentials, there is a homomorphism of $A$-modules $\varphi: \Omega_{A/R} \to M$ such that $\varphi \circ d_{A/R} = \tilde{d}$. I tried to argue that $\varphi \otimes_A id_{A'}$ would be the unique morphism $\Omega_{A/R} \otimes_A A' \to M$ satisfying the universal property - but the target of $\varphi \otimes_A id_{A'}$ is $M \otimes_A A'$, not $M$. If there was a canonical homomorphism of $A'$-modules $M \otimes_A A' \to M$, I could maybe use it to finish the proof, but I don't know if such morphism exists. Maybe I am going the wrong way.

**Edit:** Multiplication by scalar gives an obvious morphism $M \otimes_A A' \to M$, so I used this composed with $\varphi \otimes_A id_{A'}$ to define a map $\psi$ and showed that $\psi \circ d_{A'/R'} = d$. It remains to show uniqueness of $\psi$, I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $M$' is $A'$-module, there is a canonical map $M\otimes_A A'\to M$ namely the multiplication map.

So you are fine.

About Uniqueness:

Simply observe that $\Omega_{A/R}\otimes_A A' $ is generated as $A'$-module by symbols $da\otimes 1$ for $a\in A$. Now the map $\psi$ is determined by the unique map $\phi:\Omega_{A/R}\to M$.

This takes care of the uniqueness of $\psi$.

Comment: yes, I said that in the edit. do you have any tips for proving uniqueness of the morphism?

Comment: @user480840 Added the explanation for the uniqueness of $\psi$.

Comment: is $d_{A/R}$ surjective?

Comment: @user480840 No. Typical element of $\Omega_{A/R}$ is $A$-linear combination of $da$'s for $a\in A$. Elements in the images of $d_{A/R}$ are of the form $da$ for some $a\in A$.